# My site is being redirected to itself

Tags: redirect

I have been told that [my website](http://DonatePhilippines.com) is redirecting to itself – but I don't know what this means.

I was told that this is the reason it does not show up in Google and Yahoo.
My question is, where is the redirection located and how do I fix it?

Comment: I suppose you will find the redirection either in the htaccess – or in the admin panel of your webspace. Could you try to ask your hosting provider?

Comment: There does not appear to be any redirection.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a combination of SSL (HTTPS) and non-SSL (HTTP) pages on the site? If so, you may be getting caught in a redirect loop due to some issues with either your `.htaccess` file, page caching or a configuration issue on your web host.

Answer (score 1):

I had something similar happen as well. I noticed that your domain is registered through GoDaddy, have you recently changed something with your domain? Switched primary, forwarding, etc.?

If so, there is a known bug that I cam across with GoDaddy that doesn't properly redirect, causing intermittent 302 status which will cause issues with Google's ability to index. Can see [here](https://www.godaddy.com/community/Managing-Domains/My-domain-name-not-resolving-correctly-6-random-characters-are/td-p/60782).

In my case, the client switched her primary domain, and forwarded all of her other domains to point to the new primary. To fix it, we also added her old domain in Cloudflare, pointed the nameservers in GoDaddy to Cloudflare, and then set the forwarding rule in Cloudflare instead, bypassing GoDaddy. After we did this, in Search Console we set up each domain as a new property and performed several "fetches" and the issue was resolved.

You can also see how this effected our client's Google My Business Listing by checking out this thread [here](https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Enhance-Your-Presence/Google-Business-keeps-removing-my-website-address/td-p/1662668). Because of that "redirect" issue, Google kept removing the URL to the home page from her GMB listing.

I wasted a few weeks on this issue and it was a nightmare. Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your website is showing correctly on Google. To make sure Google is indexing your website:

- Go to [Google](https://www.google.com/)
- search for `site:http://donatephilippines.com/`

And see for yourself the results.